# Django include within single urls.py

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I want to make an include in my urls.py referring to another urls in the same urls.py file.

My structure is as follows:

```
├── docs
├── requirements
├── scripts
└── sonata
    ├── person
    │   ├── migrations
    │   ├── templatetags
    │   └── urls.py
    ├── registration
    │   ├── migrations
    │   └── urls.py
    └── sonata
        ├── settings
        └── urls.py
```

And I want every coming url with prefix 'pdf/' to add a value to kwargs and calling again the rest of url. This is my attempt:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html')),

    # This is my attempt for capturing the pdf prefix 
    # and calling this same file afterwards with the pdfOutput variable set to True
    url(r'^pdf/', include('sonata.urls'), kwargs={'pdfOutput':True}),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^person/', include('person.urls')),
    url(r'^registration/', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'^menu/', registration_views.menu, name='menu'),
    url(r'^customers/', person_views.customers, name='customers'),
    url(r'^employees/', person_views.employees, name='employees'),
    url(r'^alumns/', person_views.alumns, name='alumns'),
    url(r'^teaching/', person_views.docencia, name='teaching'),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)
```

Is there any way of doing this? I looked at the docs. It seems pretty clear how to pass values, but after proving I can't make the include. (I don't want either to do include() with the [array] of patterns repeating all urls. This would break DRY principle).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `include` immediately imports the included url configuration, resulting in a circular import error. You can do something like this, though:

```
sonata_patterns = [
    url(r'^$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^person/', include('person.urls')),
    url(r'^registration/', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'^menu/', registration_views.menu, name='menu'),
    url(r'^customers/', person_views.customers, name='customers'),
    url(r'^employees/', person_views.employees, name='employees'),
    url(r'^alumns/', person_views.alumns, name='alumns'),
    url(r'^teaching/', person_views.docencia, name='teaching'),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^pdf/', include(sonata_patterns), kwargs={'pdfOutput':True})
] + sonata_patterns
```

Another possibility is to use middleware to capture the `pdf` prefix and set an attribute on the request. That way, you won't have to worry if all views accept your `pdfOutput` argument.

Comment: Thank you. It's too late here now. I will test this soon.